# How do I make a link to my SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync in my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, email-confirmation

After a customer registers as a user in my application they are sent to the login page. When they log in I have a message that tells them to confirm their email. Currently when I click it it goes to a 404. Here is my send email confirmation token method:

```
private async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(string userID, string subject)
{

    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = userID, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userID, subject, "Please confirm your account by <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">clicking here</a>");
    return callbackUrl;
}
```

Here is my link in the view

```
@Html.ActionLink("click here", "SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync", "Account")
```

Comment: So this 404 is happening when you click on a link in your app's page? What url it is trying to navigate to ? Do you have a corresponding action method which matches that route pattern ?

Comment: If you asking me if there is a view for that Async, no.

Answer (score 0):

The method must be scoped as `public` if you want to reach it from outside of the controller like through a View or html link.

You need to pass your method/action parameters as a part of the link. Without arguments it will try to resolve to an action(method) without parameters which does not exist.

```
@Html.ActionLink("click here", "SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync", "Account", new {userID = "123", subject = "Welcome or something like this"}, null)
```

See also the [documentation on actionlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

Comment: I am still getting a 404. Is this anything to do with the fact that the method is private instead of public?

Comment: @Skullomania - absolutely, it has to be public if you want to call it. I did not see that until you just pointed it out, sorry.

Comment: now it navigates to a blank page with the `userID` and `subject` on it

Comment: @Skullomania - but your mail is called. The question now becomes where do you want the user to end up after they click on the link, every link takes you somewhere that is just how links work. If you wanted an asynchronous action with result and handle everything in javascript that can be done too but is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: @Skullomania - so instead of returning a `string` return an `Action` and point the user to the page where they should end up on using `return View(xxxx);`

Comment: @Skullomania - then you probably did not configure an smtp service in your asp.net identity yet or the mail is being blocked. The point is your action is being reached, that is what you needed help with.